# Beamer short forms, and automatic labelling of header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm using the `Goettingen` theme, and I'm automatically labelling the header with the name of the subsection. As the `Goettingen` theme has a side navigation bar, some of the subsections are too long to be displayed on a single line. What I'd like to do is specify a short form for the side bar (using `[...]`) and a long form for the header (using `{...}`). However, the code also inserts the short form in the header.

Can anyone get this to work (i.e., use the short form in the side bar, and the long form as the header)?

Here's a minimal working example;

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,smaller,12pt,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{helvet}

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\let\insertframetitle\insertsubsectionhead}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

\subsection[sub 1]{Subection One}

\begin{frame}{x}

Some text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional argument of the `\subsection` command specifies the subsection title to be used in the *navigation bars*. According to the Beamer manual: "`\insertsubsectionhead` inserts the name of the subsction that is *to be typeset in a navigation bar*"

So, instead of using `\let\insertframetitle\insertsubsectionhead` to insert the short version of subsection title as frame title, simply use `\let\insertframetitle\insertsubsection` (without the `head` at the end):

[image]